# PhantomJS doesn't detect element["onscroll"] after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I have the following simple webpage at URL: abcxyz.com:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function foo() {
      latestKnownScrollY = window.pageYOffset;
      console.log(latestKnownScrollY);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onscroll="foo()">
</body>
</html>
```

And the following phantomjs script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.open('http://abcxyz.com', function(status) 
  page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]["onscroll"]);
  });
  phantom.exit()
});
```

This returns `null`, which basically says that PhantomJS couldn't find the onscroll event handler associated with `body`.

However, if I query body["onscroll"] at the end of the original webpage after `<body>` (without using PhantomJS):

```
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]["onscroll"].toString());
</script>
```

Then it would return the onscroll handler.

My questions are:
1. Why is PhantomJS not able to detect the onscroll event handler of the body element?
2. When exactly is page.open() executed? After the onload event is the webpage is fired?

Comment: Have you tried to use `console.log(document.body.onscroll.toString());` instead? Also, you forgot to add `http://` for your URL. This is necessary to open any page.

Comment: That didn't work either. document.body.onscroll return null.

Comment: Ok, you can access `document.body.getAttribute("onscroll")`, but that doesn't solve anything. This may be a bug in PhantomJS (or simply an incompatibility). I haven't successfully triggered the scroll event with the most obvious ways with `addEventListener`, but I know that there must be a way, because PhantomJS can do scrolling as evidenced by the many "infinite scroll" questions here on Stack Overflow. You can try to look through the Twitter source to determine how they do it.

Comment: Interesting if the onscroll event handler is registered via `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = foo;`, then my phantomJS script is able to detect the onscroll event handler, just not with `<body onscroll="foo()">`. Any idea?